# What is best way to validate API calls, weather the request is valid or the user bypassing some calls, in web api?

Tags: c#, rest, http, .net-core, asp.net-web-api2

Thanks, I am developing one rest API in Dot.Net core. I need to secure my API calls while accessing.

I have 10 rest API calls, here few of them,

1. ValidateUser,
2. UploadDocument
3. VerifyDocument
4. ApproveDocument
5. EligibleForPersonalLoan.

The order of these calls should be sequential order, what bulleted above 
Example: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6.

if byepasser make a call request "2.UploadDocument" after the "5. EligibleForPersonalLoan" call, and this request is wrong and in this scenario the user has byepassed two calls(3 and 4), so here i want to return 'invalid request' error message. So how to handle this scenario.

Comment: Please edit the question in order to [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why not having a "Request status" on the db? I mean create an entity which keep tracks of the status of the Loan Eligibility? Each Api calls has to "update" the status request and move it foward to the next step.

Comment: To "secure" your web api JWT is the answer, but this concern the authentication which is definitely another topic. So here you have 2 challenges. First the authentication (as I imagine you did not implement anything yet) and then the status request which needs to follow some "steps"

Answer (score 0):

You could easily managed it by introducing a new enum called "LoanStatus"

```cs
public class Loan 
{

    public long Id { get; set; }

    public virtual User User{ get; set; }

    public virtual List<Document> Documents{ get; set; }

    public LoanStatus LoanStatus{ get; set; }

}

public enum LoanStatus
{       
   UserValidated,
   DocumentUploaded,
   DocumentVerified,
   DocumentApproved,
   LoanEligibility...
}
```

Each time a WebApi is called you check the LoanStatus property and see if it's in the expected status otherwise you throw a forbidden request. 
If the status is the one expected you do all your logic and then you change the status of the entity.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("verifydocument/{loadId:long}")]
public IHttpActionResult VerifyDocument(long loadId)
    {
        try
        {
            var loan= _loanService.FindLoanById(loadId);
            if (loan.LoanStatus!=null && loan.LoanStatus.Equals(LoanStatus.DocumentUploaded)
            //Do logic for the verifyDocument and update the LoanStatus to DocumentVerified
            {  
               return Ok(loanUpdated);
            }
            return Forbid();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return InternalServerError(exception);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Vote the answer or mark it as correct if it has been helpful. ;)